# how to convert a number into its 2's compliment in java

Tags: java

This is my code

```
String st;
for (int x : comp) {


st = Integer.toBinaryString(x);


 System.out.println("BINARY"+st);
}
```

here comp is a integer array and I am trying to get the binary String.
But I want to calculate the two's compliment of numbers in the comp array.
can I get any way for that ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  ~ unary operator since is bitwise negation.
After that you need to add 1.

```
int foo = 117;
food = ~foo + 1;
```

2 complement = 1 complement +1

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a method to 2 compliment a binary String in java

```
public static String compliment2(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    boolean change = false;
    for (int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (change) {
            if (arr[i] == '1') arr[i] = '0';
            else arr[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (arr[i] == '1') change = true;
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

What you do is to read from right to left all the bits. Once you find the first '1', you have to start swapping the rest of the bits to the left.